# Auto selection of category based on subject line or TAG

Tags: posts

I post to Wordpress via IFTTT triggers; however, all of my posts go into the default category set up within Wordpress. Is there any method or plugin that would review new post and then based on a preset condition move it to the desired category.

For example, if I sent a post which had Video - My New Video, it would look for the prefix Video and move the post to a category called Video etc. Thanks John

Answer (score 2):

I doubt there are any plugins out there that can do what you want "out-of-the-box", however you could probably write a plugin to do what you're looking for. Some basic boilerplate logic could look like

```
function jcharnock_insert_post_category( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
    // Only run on inserts.
    if ( $update ) {
        return;
    }

    $title_categories = array(
        'video',
        'image',
    );

    // See if the category is the first word in the title, use a delimiter for safety.
    foreach ( $title_categories as $cat ) {
        if ( 0 === stripos( $post->post_title, "{$cat} - " ) ) {
            wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $cat, 'category', false );
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'jcharnock_insert_post_category', 10, 3 );
```

**What does this do?**

With this action in place, if you were to send a post to your site named "Video - My new cool video post" or "Image - Some image post", the new posts would be assigned the respective category of 'video' or 'image'.

Title categories are delimited with a `-` (space-dash-space) so that other posts don't accidentally get miscategorized, such as "Video players that are awesome" or "Image software reviews".Of course, you can make that delimiter whatever you want, or not use it at all, it's just to help minimize mistakes.